# Unexpected constructor / extend behavior in BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, constructor, backbone.js, extend

Got really confused on how JavaScript/BackboneJS works. Let's consider the following example:

```
window.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    index: 0,
    list: [],        
    initialize: function () {
        console.log("Initializing MyView");
        console.log("this.index = " + this.index);
        console.log("this.list = [" + this.list.join(',') + "]");
        this.index++;
        this.list.push(this.index);
    }
});

var first = new MyView(),
    second = new MyView();
```

What I was expecting here is that new MyView() will create a clean copy of window.MyView "class", so the outbut would be:

```
Initializing MyView
this.index = 0
this.list = []

Initializing MyView
this.index = 0
this.list = []
```

But instead I've got

```
Initializing MyView
this.index = 0
this.list = []

Initializing MyView
this.index = 0
this.list = [1] // Very unexpected!
```

The confusing part is that integer variable "index" was in fact 0 as expected, but array "list" already contained a value from previous initialization. How come is this way?

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/fqZTp/3/

Comment: I don't know backbone, but it seems `list`/`index` are put in the prototype, so they refer to the same value thing in both instances. Setting them on initialization on a per-instance basis works: http://jsfiddle.net/fqZTp/4/. I'm not sure if this is the answer, though.

Comment: That is indeed the answer. Look at http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-149 for the implementation details of their extend function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different behavior between what happens to `list` and `index` is explained well with these two answers:

- [The difference between simply reading and actually setting an object property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1534286/29995)
- [How incrementing (++) is actually an assignment behind the scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/261948/29995)

To summarize them:

- `list` and `index` both exist on `MyView`'s prototype.
- After creating your `new MyView()`, `initialize()` operates in the context of the newly created instance (i.e. not the prototype).
- When you `push()` something onto `list`, you're pushing it onto the list object that's **referenced** by the prototype. You're not updating the reference to the list at all, just reading it.
- When you `index++`, this actually does an **assignment** (`this.index = this.index + 1`) behind the scenes. When you assign something to an object, it doesn't matter whether or not it exists on the prototype - you are **assigning it to that particular instance**. The prototype does not change.

---

For the behavior you're expecting, just set both properties in your `initialize` function:

```
window.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.index = 0;
        this.list = [];

        this.index++;
        this.list.push(this.index);
    }
});
```

Comment: That works very good. But then why (int)"index" variable acts like a object variable? It does not persist the value. While (array)"list" variable acts like a static one? What I suppose is that they both persist the value and the last return should be: this.index=1; this.list=[1];

Comment: @ViliusPau - Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1534286/29995) - it's an *excellent* explanation.