# Why declare an instance property in prototype instead of constructor?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I completely understand why it's better to use the prototype instead of the constructor to define a class **method**, (i.e. [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)) However, I recently came across a [HashMap class](http://stjernegaard.net/jsdoc/symbols/src/jsdoc-toolkit_js_cols_HashMap.js.html) that defines the `count` **property** in the prototype and the `map` property in the constructor:

```
js_cols.HashMap = function(opt_map, var_args) {

    /**
     * Underlying JS object used to implement the map.
     * @type {!Object}
     * @private
     */
    this.map_ = {};

    /...
}

/**
 * The number of key value pairs in the map.
 * @private
 * @type {number}
 */
js_cols.HashMap.prototype.count_ = 0;
```

Are there advantages of declaring an instance property like `count` in the prototype instead of saying `this.count_ = 0;` in the constructor? And if so, why not also `js_cols.HashMap.prototype.map_ = {};`?

Edit: A similar question was asked, [Why declare properties on the prototype for instance variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751230/why-declare-properties-on-the-prototype-for-instance-variables-in-javascript), and "default values" was raised as a use case, but it was not explained *why* this is more desirable than just defining the default value in the constructor.

Comment: Note: If an instance tries to increment "js_cols.HashMap.prototype.count_" via ++this.count, it will only increment that instance's local count property. It will not effect other instance's value for this.count. The only way that value gets incremented (for all instances) is by explicitly accessing it via the prototype object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the `HashMap` class is the best example of the benefits of declaring an *instance* property in the prototype. Consider instead a `Response` class:

```
function Response() {
   this.headers = {};
}
Response.prototype.statusCode = 200;
```

All instances of `Response` will share the `statusCode` of `200` — literally, the same number in memory will be shared across all instances. This makes sense if you expect your server to respond with status code 200 *most of the time*. Those `Requests` that need different status codes can overwrite their default `statusCode`, which creates a new number in memory.

I.e. If you have 10,000 concurrent requests, and 5 of them are 404's, you got away with only having 6 numbers in memory to represent all 10,000 `statusCodes`.

In summation, it might be worth it to use prototype if you expect a lot of instances to share the same default value *most of the time*. Otherwise, you can chalk it up to coding style. (Obviously for *static* properties, always use prototype.)

*Note* see Lucas's answer for why a property that's an object (e.g. `map` or `headers`) can't be in the prototype: all instances would be sharing the same *reference*, thus any update to that reference would update all instances.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how it is used, are you sure `count_` doesn't define the number of hash buckets there are, rather than the exact count of how many items are in the hash?  Defining variables in the prototype is good if you expect the value to remain constant and global for all instances of the class, since only memory for one variable is being used regardless of how many class instances you make.

Comment: I'm positive that it means the # of key/val pairs. In the insert function: `this.count_++;`.

Comment: Not sure what the idea was, but it looks like a misjudgment in design to me.  If you ever need two instances of HashMap you may run into a problem.

Comment: Apparently, according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261219/class-variables-in-javascript if you assign a new value to `this.count_` you essentially create a new instanced variable in your class that hides the prototype, but you don't actually change the prototype value.  So in essence, you really are just using an instanced value at that point.

Comment: Yeah, it will only be a global update if it's `this.prototype.count_++;`. So I guess the idea behind this that if the property never deviates from the default value, you've saved yourself a bit of memory?

Comment: @moonprismpower : Very little memory is saved. The only way you'd save memory is if you had a million instances of empty maps; they'd all share that zero count until the first name value pair is added. Your own accepted answer indeed shows a more practical example.

Answer (score 1):

It works for `count_`, but it wouldn't work for `map_`.

`count_` is an integer value, while `map_` is an object reference. If a `HashMap` instance updates `count_`, it will essentially create a `count_` property on its own instance.

But, if it inserts something to the `map_`, as all instances share the same `map_` reference,  all instances would end up with the same values in the map. This wouldn't work, and that's why every instance get a different `map_` reference in its constructor.

As for the `count_` property, it's declared in the prototype just as a default. It would be the same if it was instantiated in the constructor. I guess it's just a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 0):

prototyping is the JavaScript OOP way to extend and inherit. So it is the way to make code reusable. You may be the programmer of the constructor, but others may wish to extend your Objects, if they reuse your code. And you may not wish, that they hacking around in your code.

Good description is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Greetings

Axel

Answer (score 0):

Consider class *Customer* representing a customer of a bank whose interest rates are a subject to change. For each customer you have to calculate interest, which was set per the the policy of the bank. In this scenario there is a variable *interest* whose value is same for certain customers, also the change to this variable must be propagated to all the customers. Let's model it in JavaScript.

```
var Customer = function(name, amount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = amount;
};

Customer.prototype.interest = 10; //default value. which changes later
Customer.prototype.computeInterest = function() {
    this.amount += this.amount * this.interest / 100; //assume they are savings account
};

var me = new Customer('Ajinkya', 100);
var you = new Customer('RKBWS47', 1000);
var somebody = new Customer('Jon Doe', 10000);

me.computeInterest();
you.computeInterest();
somebody.computeInterest();

console.log(me.amount); //110
console.log(you.amount); //1100
console.log(somebody.amount); //11000

Customer.prototype.interest = 20; //yay!

me.computeInterest();
you.computeInterest();
somebody.computeInterest();

console.log(me.amount); //132
console.log(you.amount); //1320
console.log(somebody.amount); //13200
```

This is true for the methods too. They are shared by all the instances of the class with the *this* variable set to the invoking object or instance. You can also use the properties defined on constructor functions to simulate static methods or the way I like to remember them, methods called on classes. Using `this.interest` in our example wouldn't have allowed us to share it across `me`, `you` and `somebody`.

EDIT: I have answered assuming that the HashMap example is used to illustrate your question.

Comment: My question was a little ambiguous, I've updated it: I'm asking about instance properties, not static properties, and why it's preferable to set them in the prototype instead of the constructor.